# No sound on iMac

Tags: sound, mac

My front speaker and headphone jack don't work. I tried all the similar questions and it didn't work. I checked with alsamixer if it's mute

```
~ $inxi -SMA
System:    Host: iMac-feat-Linux Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.9 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Apple product: iMac18 1 v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-4B682C642B45593E v: iMac18 1 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Apple v: 181.0.0.0.0 date: 01/31/2020
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.3.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is Q&A for Ubuntu OS not for Apple products, you can ask on Super User forums alike.

Comment: Sorry I have no useful knowledge for your hardware, but I'd suggest the usual documentation, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure